# Can you pass an object's attribute name as a string in a function in Python? (cryptowatch API)

Tags: python

I'm making an API call using cryptowatch's sdk https://github.com/cryptowatch/cw-sdk-python. The data I am trying to retrieve is stored as an object's attribute. Depending on the timeframe, this attribute is named differently.

E.g. If  we are requesting daily Bitcoin data ('**1d**' timeframe), we can retrieve it by calling the object attribute as follows: object.of_**1d**

If we are requesting weekly Bitcoin data ('**1w**' timeframe), we can retrieve it by calling the object attribute as follows: object.of_**1w**

I'm trying to write a function which calls the market data based on a period that you specify as a parameter, as below:

```
def get_price_action(exchange, market, timeframe):
    candles=cw.markets.get("{}:{}".format(exchange, market)
                           , ohlc=True
                           , periods=["{}".format(timeframe)])
    #need to access attribute based on timeframe here:
    df = pd.DataFrame(candles.of_'{}'.format(timeframe))
    return df
```

So that when I call get_price_action('KRAKEN', 'BTC:USD', '1h') it will retrieve all hourly price data for bitcoin/usd in the kraken exchange.

But am getting a syntax error when trying to retrieve the attribute.

Can someone help me to find a way to pass the attribute name as a parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use the `getattr` built-in function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(getattr(candles, 'of_{}'.format(timeframe)))
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr